# finding corresponding value to maximum

Tags: matlab

Let say I have a 5x5 matrix

```
A B C D E

1 5 7 2 3
2 1 9 8 5
3 1 2 3 1
4 1 3 4 2
5 2 9 0 1
```

and I need to find the max of `B` (which would be 5) and its corresponding value in `A` (which would be 1), how do I do that?

Comment: Please have a look into the documentation http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/max.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

max actually returns both the vlaue and the location f it. If M is your 5x5 matrix :

```
[mb,i] = max(M(:,2));
ma = M(i,1);
```

should do the trick.

If mb is irrelevant to you,

```
[~,i] = max(M(:,2));
ma = M(i,1);
```

will discard the value return of max